# How to get faultstring in SoapFault?

Tags: android, soap, soapfault

I am calling Soap API in android and i get the below error,

```
SoapFault - faultcode: '2' faultstring: 'Access denied.' faultactor: 'null' detail: null
at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:141)
at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:140)
at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:100)
at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:214)
at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:96)
at com.magentodemo.customer.MagentoCustomer$GetCustomerDetailsTask.doInBackground(MagentoCustomer.java:714)
at com.magentodemo.customer.MagentoCustomer$GetCustomerDetailsTask.doInBackground(MagentoCustomer.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

i want to retrieve Access denied message from this SoapFault,

how can I get that message ?

Comment: your `NAME_SPACE` and `SOAP_ACTION` are correct..?? and also check your input parameters...

Answer (score 2):

I get the solution of my question,

i have the following code

```
private class Login extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            // Soap Call

        } catch (SoapFault fault) {
            Log.v("TAG", "soapfault = "+fault.getMessage());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

i just add the Catch block for SoapFault and i get faultstring, thats it.

Comment: I am not able to put the catch block for SOapFault.. it is throwing an error as `Unreachable catch block for SoapFault. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body`..why am i getting this error?? Any Idea ??

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the SoapFault class API's method to get your requirements ? Please check the respective from below link :
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPFault.html#getFaultString()